# Card Deal Function Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a function to shuffle deck of 52 cards (list of integers) and 'deal' them to 4 different players evenly, i.e. 4 players should get 13 cards each. However for some reason when I run it, all the players get 52 cards each, a shuffled version of the deck, can someone please offer some help as to how to alter the code below to cut the deck up evenly and give it to each player?

```
def deal_cards(deck, Nplayers):
    shuffle(deck)
    cards = len(deck)
    hands = Nplayers*[[]]
    if Nplayers == 0:
        return None
    for card in range(cards):
        player = card % Nplayers
        hands[player].append(deck[card])

    return hands
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not building 4 lists, you are building one list, referenced 4 times:

```
hands = Nplayers*[[]]
```

Multiplying a list does not create copies of the values; instead only the *reference* is copied; appending to `hands[0]` will be reflected in all other references to the same list.

Use a list comprehension:

```
hands = [[] for _ in range(Nplayers)]
```

It'll be easiest to use slicing:

```
def deal_cards(deck, Nplayers):
    shuffle(deck)
    l = len(deck)
    portion = l // Nplayers
    return [deck[i:i + portion] for i in range(0, len(deck), portion]
```